# jQuery UI Accordion on ul

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-accordion

How do I get the [jQuery UI Accordion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI#Widgets) to work when I need to put a wrapper around each element?

Example HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
     <h3><a href="#">header</a></h3>
     <div>
         Content goes here
     </div>
  </li>
  <li>
     <h3><a href="#">header</a></h3>
     <div>
         Content goes here
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I just can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 13):

<s>You cannot make the accordion work with your current markup.  Elements must be siblings like this:</s>

```
<div id="parentAccordionDiv">
    <h3><a href="#">header</a></h3>
    <div>
        Content goes here
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">header</a></h3>
    <div>
        Content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

I stand corrected.  I got an accordion to work fine like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#accordion').accordion();
    })
</script>
<ul id="accordion">
  <li>
     <h3><a href="#">header</a></h3>
     <div>
         Content goes here
     </div>
  </li>
  <li>
     <h3><a href="#">header</a></h3>
     <div>
         Content goes here
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```